# JQuery select remove where class != "dgItem"

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i want to remove the following

```
<tr><td style="padding-left:20px;" class="content">
```

This works fine with

```
$(".content").first().remove();
```

But on some of my pages I have this

```
<tr class="dgItem"><td class="content">
```

And it gets removed.
Is it possible to make the JQuery only select the first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7c7kD/

```
$('tr:not(.dgItem) > td.content').remove();
```

Using [jQuery's `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), this will remove `td.content` elements that are a direct child of a `<tr>` that does not have the class `.dgItem`.

Comment: Your description is a little off, but the answer is correct... It removes `td.content` elements that are direct children of a `tr` that is **not** `.dgItem`.  +1

Comment: @gnarf - Very true. Thanks for the heads up! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a second class name to the first type of table column `class="content anotherclassname"`? then call `$(".anotherclassname").remove();`